# Main nav takes on hover style on page load

Tags: css, menu

I have a horizontal nav menu that I am working on. I have one issue left with this menu. When the user navigates to a page, I would like the main li to remain hovered. Right now, the li does not remain in a hovered state and simply reverts to default. Do I need to give the body a class to make this work or is there another way? The code snippet can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/SeasonEnds/LSmfN/

Ideally, the Read tab should take on the hover styles upon on loading the page, but go away as the user hovers over the other main nav links.

Comment: The css classes would be something like ul#topnav li.on {background: #f3f3f3;} ul#topnav li.on a{color:#828282;} but when you hover the class .on remains hovered which isn't what I'd like it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlight on the active element shouldn't really disappear when the user hovers on another top-level link as this is bad for usability - if the user doesn't click on a link then they've lost the visual clue as to where they are on your site.

I've amended the css slightly:

```
ul#topnav li.on a    {color:#828282; background: #f3f3f3; }
ul#topnav li a:hover {background: #f3f3f3; color:#828282;}
ul#topnav li a:visited {color:#828282; }
```

I've also added a bit of jQuery to keep the colour of the active top-level link as you hover over the children:

```
$("li a").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().toggleClass("top-level-highlight");
});
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LSmfN/14/

Comment: I think I like this solution the best. I think you are probably right about having that link disappear. The only problem was having multiple links with grey backgrounds in the top level nav looked pretty bad. So, I changed the other hovers to a white underline with no background change. Now, it looks pretty good and works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the menu to know which page it's on without either the server setting the active menu element, or JS indicating the active element.

Here's what you can do - add a class "here" to indicate the current position:

```
ul#topnav li:hover, ul#topnav li.here {background: #f3f3f3;
```

Detect the current page using js:

```
//var here = document.location+"" //for production
var here = "/home.html" //for testing  
 if(here.indexOf("home.html")>-1) {

     $('ul#topnav li').eq(0).addClass('here')
     $('ul#topnav li').mouseout(function() {
          $('ul#topnav li').removeClass('here')
     })
 } //repeat for all pages
```

Comment: I liked this solution as well. The only problem is that when I hover over the menu and then move the mouse off of the menu, the nav was no longer highlighted. Also, I think my approach of having the link disappear when hovering over the other top-level-nav items didn't really make any sense. Thanks for the time!!!